# Functional setState counter

Tags: reactjs, functional-programming

Im trying to do a counter for a pagination component that use 4 differents tabs so i have to keep track of each tab pagination with the folloing code:

```
loadMoreVisits(activeTab) {
  this.setState(
      state => ({
          page: {
            ...state.page,
            [activeTab]: {
              ...state.page[activeTab],
              pageNumber: this.state.page[activeTab].pageNumber + 1
            }  
          }
      })
  );
  this.props.requestVisits({
      pageNumber: this.state.page[activeTab].pageNumber,
      perPage: this.state.page.perPage,
      status: activeTab
  });
}
```

a button is calling this handler and my problem is the first time i click on the handlers it dosen't count +1 after the second time it starts working normaly.

Initial state:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        page: {
            nuevo: {pageNumber: 0},
            confirmado: {pageNumber: 0},
            finalizado: {pageNumber: 0},
            cancelado: {pageNumber: 0},
            perPage: 5
        },
        activeTab: 'nuevo'
    };
}
```

Comment: How does your initial state look like ?

Answer (score 1):

As you are using state updater function, you already have `state` in the scope. Why don't you use the scoped variable instead of `this.state`.

There is a possibility that `this.state` is stale as it might be batched.

```
this.setState(
      state => ({
          page: {
            ...state.page,
            [activeTab]: {
              ...state.page[activeTab],
              pageNumber: state.page[activeTab].pageNumber + 1
                          ^^^
            }  
          }
      })
  );
```